# Getting error message Traceback (most recent call last): File "input/code.py", line 1, in <module> a= int(input())

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

Hi this is simple code it returns sum of a and b and asks user for input.
this is for competitive programming website for example code forces but its not codeforces website.

Iam getting this dumb error i dont know why
[Ther error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmSVq.png)

my code

```
a= int(input())
b= int(input())

sum= int(a)+ int(b)

print(sum)
```

can anyone tell why iam getting this error

Comment: `input()` returns the entire line. `a = int(input())` tries to convert the string `3 2` into an integer, resulting in your error

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment, `input()` returns the entire line. You must split it by spaces to get `['3','2']` and then convert those to integers.

One way to do that would be

```
line = input().split()
a,b = int(line[0]), int(line[1])
```

Or if you're into one liners,

```
a,b = map(int, input().split())
```